# Firestore query: how to filter by two fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter documents by their location (using geohash) but I also want to order them by timestamp (to get the latest documents first). The following query fetches the nearby documents but they are not ordered by timestamp.

```
DocumentSnapshot<Object?>? lastFetchedDoc;  // used for pagination

Future<void> getReviews() async {

  Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query = firestore
            .collectionGroup("reviews")
            .where("city", whereIn: ['New York', 'Philadelphia', 'Washington'])
            .orderBy('geohash')
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .where('geohash', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "dph")
            .where('geohash', isLessThanOrEqualTo: "dp~")
            .limit(10);

  if (lastFetchedDoc != null) {
      query = query.startAfterDocument(lastFetchedDoc!);
  }

  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await query.get();
  lastFetchedDoc = snapshot.docs.last;
}
```

How can I create a query that fetches the nearby documents ordered by timestamp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query results will first be ordered by `geohash` and only then on `timestamp`, meaning that the value of the `timestamp` field only affects the order of the results for documents where the value of `geohash` is the same.

There is no way to change this behavior for range queries such as the one you're doing. If you want to further process the documentation in order of timestamp, you will have to reorder them in your application code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, reordering the documents in my application will not solve the problem because I will not be able to fetch the latest documents to begin with. Since I'm paginating, I will not fetch all documents at once. That means I may have older documents in the first page, and as the user scrolls down, they may see newer documents, which is not what I want. If I understand correctly, this seems to be a limitation of the database currently, in that I cannot really fetch the latest documents while at the same time doing a range query in firestore, correct?

Comment: Correct. You will have to choose what takes priority: filtering by date or filtering by distance, you can't do both in a query as Firestore only support a range filter on a single field: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

Comment: Thanks for confirming. How can I make filtering by date a priority, but still filter by distance? That would work for me because I don't care about the order of the documents by distance, as long as I'm getting documents within a certain distance. When I try to put the orderBy(timestamp) before the orderBy(geohash) it complains that the initial orderBy() field has to be the same as the where() field parameter.

Comment: You can't do that in the database query. To be able to *filter* on geohash, you'll need to order on that first. The only options are to do one of the filters in the query, and the order in the application code, or to change your data model to not require two range queries (e.g. using a city name or something like that to replace the distance condition).